# VMWare Recognizes Wifi but not the VM itself

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine

I am having trouble with my VMware Workstation. Currently trying to connect my Vm to the internet, but I am not getting any luck. Workstation does recognize it, as shown here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUibK.png]

But ultimately my VM doesn't connect. What could I be doing wrong?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BwD4.png]

EDIT: When trying to do the bridged option, this is what I get: 
/imgur/zKmTIW3
/imgur/kgPZnYB
/imgur/qSxW8j9
(It's not letting me post more than 2 links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest trying to use the Bridged Connection mode. This replicates the connection state of the host machine, and often has a higher success rate in terms of connecting VMs. NAT is similar to bridged connection, but it shares the connection state instead of replicating it. This can cause some connection and port forwarding issues, and I've often seen it make the connection local only (if port forwarding isn't configured correctly).

Comment: When I do that, I get the same icon at the bottom of my Workstation. But when it searched for a signal it doesn't work.

Comment: The bridged connection replicates the host machine state. If the host machine is not connected, the guest will not be either.

Comment: http://imgur.com/zKmTIW3
http://imgur.com/kgPZnYB
http://imgur.com/qSxW8j9 still no luck, looks like there's something interrupting the bridge.

Comment: Have you checked to ensure you're only replicating the state of the wireless card? By default, all connections are activated for replication

Comment: I have tried with and without checking the "replicate physical network connection state" option.

Comment: That's not what I was talking about. https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-4D35D1FC-5926-45A8-96B1-42C922DA97E9.html
That link shows how to select which physical adapter the virtual machine replicates. Ensure it is set to the correct adapter, being your wireless adapter

Comment: If my answer helped you solve the issue, make sure you select it as the "Correct" answer by clicking on the tick. Thanks!.